# Performing same operation on multiple named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of named ranges within a sheet that must get cleared every day. Currently I have it set up within VBA like this:

```
Range("CustomList1").ClearContents
Range("CustomList2").ClearContents
Range("CustomList3").ClearContents
Range("CustomList4").ClearContents
Range("CustomList5").ClearContents
(+15 more)
```

Not really a big deal but I feel like there must be a better way of going about it. That being said after doing some searching I didn't really see anything about looping through multiple named ranges. Any ideas/thoughts on this?

Comment: Skin has already given you an answer. You can also store all the `customlist` range into one `MasterRange` and then simply call `Range("MasterRange").ClearContents`?

Comment: When you say store all the `customlist` range do you mean storing their respective _names_ or _addresses_?

Comment: I have posted an answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 to 20
    Range("CustomList" & i).ClearContents
Next
```

... something like that.

If you had some sort of naming convention for named ranges that you want to clear, you could do something like this which means you don't ever need to update your code ...

```
Dim objName As Name

For Each objName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(1, objName.Name, "NamedRange", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
        With objName.RefersToRange
            .Worksheet.Range(.Address).ClearContents
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Figured it would be easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick make sure you flag the answer that works for you. Helps us all, just a friendly reminder.

Comment: Done. Had tried to right off the bat but it said I had to wait and just now got back to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Skin's solution will work if the name is consistent, but if not, you could always create an array with all the range names.

Something Like

`RngArray = Array("CustomList1","CustomList2","CustomList3, etc.")
For i = 0 to 19
    Range(RngArray(i)).ClearContents
Next`

Comment: Good to know. I had actually toyed with both methods but my understanding of the nuances within VBA is pathetic lol. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

A Union may be more typing than a loop but it completes the operation in a single statement.

```
Union(Range("CustomList1"), Range("CustomList2"), Range("CustomList3"), _
      Range("CustomList4"), Range("CustomList5"), Range("CustomList6"), _
      Range("CustomList7"), Range("CustomList8"), Range("CustomList9"), _
      Range("CustomList10"), Range("CustomList11"), Range("CustomList12"), _
      Range("CustomList13"), Range("CustomList14"), Range("CustomList15"), _
      Range("CustomList16"), Range("CustomList17"), Range("CustomList18"), _
      Range("CustomList19"), Range("CustomList20")).ClearContents
```

This method would likely be better suited to named ranges with abstract or dissimilar naming conventions.

Comment: I have plenty that fit the description so this does help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this slightly differently.

I would store the names under one name in the **Formula==>Names Manager** as shown below.

[image]

And then I will only use the below every where. No need for several lines of code everytime you want to clear the range.

```
Range("MyCustomList").ClearContents
```

Comment: Very interesting. Would have never thought to take this route even with all the time I've spent searching through name manager.